# targeting elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I'm using html5/css3 modal window from here
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/
, you turn it off by clicking on link

```
<a href="#close">X</a>
```

but how could I make it to work like this with a function?

```
<div onclick="someFunction">
content
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div onclick="someFunction('close')">content</div>

function someFunction(action){
  window.location.hash=action;
}
```